# How to remove duplicates right beneath original response?

Tags: r, duplicates

Background: I have a survey attached to a excel sheet and at times duplication of a response takes place. This is due to user interaction.The duplication takes place right beneath the original response. I would like the R to delete the duplications that takes place next to/right beneath the original response. I would like the original response to be kept. Is there a way to target the duplicated responses right beneath the original one?

If my dataframe looks this:

```
     Area   Year  Course    Tested  Grade  
1   Git      1    Material    Y       A
2   Ort      3    Fabric      Y       B
3   Pinst    2    Pattern     N       NA
4   Coker    1    Fashion     Y       B+
5   Coker    1    Fashion     Y       B+
6   South    4    Business    N       NA
```

This is what I would want:

```
     Area   Year  Course    Tested  Grade  
1   Git      1    Material    Y       A
2   Ort      3    Fabric      Y       B
3   Pinst    2    Pattern     N       NA
4   Coker    1    Fashion     Y       B+
5   South    4    Business    N       NA
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to only delete the duplicates if it happens in consecutive rows and keep it if they happen elsewhere you can use `rleidv` along with `duplicated` :

```
df[!duplicated(data.table::rleidv(df)),]

#   Area Year   Course Tested Grade
#1   Git    1 Material      Y     A
#2   Ort    3   Fabric      Y     B
#3 Pinst    2  Pattern      N  <NA>
#4 Coker    1  Fashion      Y    B+
#6 South    4 Business      N  <NA>
```